# didSelectRowAtIndexPath in UITableViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a HomeViewController which is loaded with views. On the top is the map view, so now when I create the table view on the top of it which does not cover the whole screen but little portion of it(actually its a drop down list in the form of tableview), it displays fine with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` working fine but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not working at all.. I have tried using break point on it but its not calling this method actually infect it is selecting the view at the back i.e. the map view. Clicking on the table view is actually changing the map view behind..

I am having the table view coming from another class which is inherited by the `HomeViewController`

I am using some NIDropDown class .. Its working fine if no view is behind it (only superview) but not woking if it has any view behind

Comment: DId you attached delegate of UITableView ?  DataSource are for data, and events are on the delegate.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot I assume he did. `licking on the table view is actually changing the map view behind.` The table view in the front isn't registering the touch event.

Comment: @TalibShabbirHussain check if your table view has selections enabled, user interaction enabled and if your tableview is created on top of mapview and not behind it, also check if you set your delegate properly

Comment: Please show me storyboard(UITableView).

Comment: @David Ansermot I have put delegate=self in the inherited class

Comment: @IxPaka and it is been created dynamically on button click event. just have a title on it..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Few things to be ensured-
1) As you said your table view is on top of the map view. If this is the case than it's alright.

2) Check if the user interaction is enabled for the table view or not.

3) Check if you have set the delegate of the table view(responsible for detecting events on table view).

4) Check if you have not set the delegate to nil somewhere and still the table view is visible.

I think if you follow the above steps than table view's events should be triggered, otherwise it will be good if you post your code to get some other clue regarding the issue.

Comment: I am using some NIDropDown class .. Its working fine (if I select it performing some event) if no view is behind it (only superview) but not woking if it has any view behind

Comment: I am not sure but it could be a reason that you are adding two views on a super view like this 1)adding Table view  2)adding any other view. After adding both views are you bringing the other view to front or enabling the user interaction of other view? It could be

Answer (score 1):

That `cellForRowAtIndexPath` works is an indication that the `datasource` property (`UITableViewDataSource`) is properly set.

If `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not firing, you should check if the `delegate` property (`UITableViewDelegate`) is properly set, either in Interface Builder or in code.

Answer (score 1):

After read your problem, i strongly believe there will be two issue :

**1) Map view issue**, if you shows table view as *callout view

**Reason:**

You supposed to use “`MKAnnotationView`” callout view for show drop down over map.

if you do so then make sure `MKAnnotationView` view height would be exact same of your drop down view’s(NIDropdown view’s) height.

Table view not able to get touch, that's why it would not send message of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to it's `deletegte`.

In your case might be Map view getting touch, which did not suppose to get until table view is at screen.

**2) Table view rest out of bound on super view**

**Reason:**

in such case table view display normally but actually its bound goes out of own super view bound.